# How to print out console in Swift Package Manager project xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I'm creating a SPM project and I need to check if the data I get from an API is correct.
How can I print out this data?

I tried to create a view inside the SPM and adding it to an App project and it works, but it doesn't exist an easier alternative?

Console doesn't show anything, no print no logs...

[image with code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLIzH.png)

Comment: [Logger](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logger) is one option

Comment: Can you give me an example pls? I'm really new to swift and I tried the code from developer apple, so many errors I don't know why :(

Comment: Example of what? There is no code involved in this question so it is very hard to give a meaningful example. Also, if you are very new with swift then maybe just use `print` statements for now (I don't understand why it shouldn't work)

Comment: I can't see nothing in console in SPM or App project, don't know what's happening. I would like to add an image of what I'm trying to execute. I'm also new writing a post. How could I show it to you?

Comment: You can edit your question and add more information.

Comment: Ok, I've add the image in the link "image with code"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.
I still have to add the package to an app project to use the console and debugger.

But my problem was not calling the function inside @main struct app.
Now it displays prints and it's all OK.

Thank you all

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking to get output from within a view, try using something along the lines of

`let _ = print("your data here")`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).